# Can a higher power-rated USB-C PD power adapter be used to charge a PD device if power specs at least meet or exceed the device requirements?

Tags: power-supply, usb-c, usb-pd

Quite simply, can I use my new 65w Dell USB-C PD power adapter, that I use for my bigger laptop, to charge my smaller USB-C PD devices such as a tablet.

The tablet supposedly charges at a PD rate of 12V@2.5amps.  Will a bigger PD adapter that exceeds 2.5amps@12V work without a problem?

I assume that a device will only draw the amount of current it needs.

Comment: Hello. Please see https://superuser.com/questions/1460601/can-a-higher-power-rated-usb-c-pd-power-adapter-be-used-to-charge-a-pd-device-if for a similar question

Comment: @davidmneedham, that sure is similar; in fact it's the same question.  :-)  Looks like you grabbed the link from the wrong question.

Comment: Oops, I meant to link https://superuser.com/questions/1209845/usb-c-chargers-is-it-safe-to-charge-a-phone-with-a-laptops-power-supply

Comment: Joe, your assumptions are correct.  If the only difference is the charger is capable of providing more current than needed, it isn't a problem.  The device will use only what it needs.

Comment: Tested and confirmed.  No problems at all. Thanks!